# Contact Form on the same page

Tags: php

I have a contact form below and when I submit the contact form it sends me in another page saying "Your Message was sent!", but I don't want that so I need to just display a simple message inside the contact form saying "Your Message was sent"

And I found many threads here with submit forms on the same page but still wasn't able to do this and I'm very beginner with PHP and other back end languages so if someone would help me this would appreciate a lot.

```css
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent= " From:  $name, \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Email";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error");
echo "Your Message was sent !";
?>
```

```html
        
             <form method="POST" action="contact-form.php">      

         <input name="name" type="text" class="message" placeholder="Name" />  
 
     <input name="email" type="text" class="message" placeholder="Email"  />

  <textarea name="message" class="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>

             <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>

          </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent= " From:  $name, \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New Email";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error");
    echo "Your Message was sent !";
 }
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input name="name" type="text" class="message" placeholder="Name" />  
  <input name="email" type="text" class="message" placeholder="Email"  />
  <textarea name="message" class="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you it works but is there any way I can customize "Your message was sent" with a different color"?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then you can make it `<div class="alert alert-success">Your message sent</div>` otherwise you can do like `<div style="color:green">Your Message sent</div>`

Comment: I see it works now it's styled, but any idea why it shows the message "You Message sent" even I haven't submitted the contact forms, it shows this message when I open the contact page without submitting and I want to show only on submit?

Comment: You may update line `if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){` to `if(isset($_POST['name]) && !empty($_POST['name])){`

Comment: updated that code with new code u told me to add and now it shows this error?
http://prntscr.com/ohfyjb
http://prntscr.com/ohfyqu

Comment: well, you need to add isset condition too. please see my comments again.

Comment: I am new to PHP and still can't solve this as it shows the error still? And I tried this but it doesn't work still? 
if(isset($_POST['name]) && !empty(isset($_POST['name])){

Comment: ok can you email at `ping@naveedramzan.com` and i will update for you.

Comment: sent you an email

Comment: This is my code as you asked on my email because I deleted your conversation on Gmail and I cannot find it https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/xvbxeP

Comment: HI, I checked your code. You need to update from `if(isset($_POST['name]) && !empty(isset($_POST['name])){` to `if(isset($_POST['name]) && !empty($_POST['name])){` as we are checking in first condition that is set and in second is not empty.

Comment: It doesn't show the error anymore but there's an issue with Email that I don't receive messages on my Inbox anymore and it was working first with your code but don't know what's the issue maybe it's with the SMTP, but thank you for all :)

Comment: yup it could be smtp setting issue. 
You most welcome Kindly upvote my answer

Comment: yes it's probably some issues with SMTP and upvoted your question but I need to have over 15 reputations to upvote

Comment: ah ok. Better luck next time :)

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form you have instructed it to go to "contact-form.php".

In contact-form.php you have the code to display the 'Your message was sent!' response.

If you change the action attribute to action="" and move the code from contact-form.php into the file that holds the actual contact form HTML, then providing that file is also a .php file, you should see the message appear on the page with the contact form.

It's hard without knowing the rest of your setup but essentially, that's how you'd do it.

Comment: So If I leave the action blank then I would not need contact.php file in a new file but just add the PHP code in index.html file where I have contact form elements right?
And if I would add the contact form in PHP then do I need to rename index.html to index.php?

Comment: If you leave action blank it will simply refresh the page, which is what you want, and if you move the PHP to index.html then you will need to rename it to index.php so that it can run it. Then it should work for you.

Comment: oh got it thanks and just the last question, I have other files with HTML, like index.html, about.html, etc and when I will change contact.html to contact.php because I have a contact form in contact.html and would it be okay if I would have some other files .html and contact.php? Because it's a simple website that doesn't need PHP expect contact.php form?

Comment: I don’t think it really matters that much if it’s .htmk it .php so I always opt for .php, it doesn’t matter that some are different extensions

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Html Form File and php code file both should be same
also your form action should be call same file

Example :
File Name : contact-form.php

<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent= " From:  $name, \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New Email";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error");
    echo "Your Message was sent !";
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="contact-form.php">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="message" placeholder="Name" />
    <input name="email" type="text" class="message" placeholder="Email" />
    <textarea name="message" class="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```